# mahout recommender increase input parameter

Tags: java

I need to build recommender with UserId,ItemId,Preference,Duration as input where Duration is the time(Time the user viewed the page). Already i build itembased and userbased recommender with userid,itemid,preference as input. So i need to increase the input parameter which affects the recommendation.

For example- 1012,112,4.0,3.45 is my input.

where 1012 is userid
       112 is itemid
       4.0 is preference
      3.45 is duration

Thanks for the guidance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.
Check CARSkit alg

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03780v1.pdf